# Redux Form Semantic UI React Dropdown meta:touched not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, semantic-ui-react

Redux Form Semantic UI React Dropdown meta:touched not working

My Redux form has two Semantic UI React Dropdown components. One dropdown the user selects a month (January thru December) and the other the user selects a year (2020 thru 2030). I have a requirement to validate that the month and year provider by the user is not in the past. For example, it is now May 2020 and if the user selects January 2020 an error needs to be shown to the user.

I’ve created a validator that properly works and creates an error for the above condition. The problem is that the Dropdown component’s “touched” meta is always false so the error is never displayed to the user.

Code for my DropdownInput component is shown below.

If a remove “touched” from the error label, the error displays immediately before the user has a chance to input their date… not a good user experience.

Any suggestions as to how to get the Dropdown component to update to “true” when the user makes a selection would be appreciated. I’ve also used the Semantic UI React Select component in place of the Dropdown component and have the same result.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Label, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const SelectInput = ({
    input,
    multiple,
    options,
    placeholder,
    size,
    style,
    label,
    meta: { touched, error },
}) => {
    console.log(`DropdownInput: touched=${touched} error=${error}`);
    return (
        <Form.Field error={touched && !!error}>
            {label && <label>{label}</label>}
            <Dropdown
                selection
                value={input.value || null}
                onChange={(e, data) => input.onChange(data.value)}
                multiple={multiple}
                options={options}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                size={size}
                style={style}
            />
            {touched && error && (
                <Label basic color='red'>
                    {error}
                </Label>
            )}
        </Form.Field>
    );
};

export default SelectInput;
```

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. One thing to consider is that you are in control of the dropdown options, so perhaps the best approach is to filter the dropdown options to only show allowable values. For example, if the user sets year=2020, then perhaps the month dropdown should automatically filter to not show past months like January, etc. Then you don't need to worry about flagging invalid values. I think this is a better user exerience anyway. This may not work in all cases, but it will work for my use case (and perhaps yours, too).